# Display method to display results from other methods Java

Tags: java, object, methods

I'm trying to show the results from GCD and LCM using the display method. I try accessing the numbers object in the display method and it cannot resolve the symbol. Everything works with the code I'm just not sure how else I can access the numbers object inside the display method. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TwoNumbers numbers = getNumbers();

    System.out.println(numbers.getNum1());
    System.out.println(+numbers.getNum2());

    GCD(numbers.getNum1(), numbers.getNum2());
    System.out.println(GCD(numbers.getNum1(), numbers.getNum2()));

    LCM(numbers.getNum1(), numbers.getNum2());
    System.out.println(LCM(numbers.getNum1(), numbers.getNum2()));
}


public static TwoNumbers getNumbers(){
    int num1;
    int num2;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
    num1 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your second number");
    num2 = input.nextInt();

    return new TwoNumbers(num1, num2);

}

public static int GCD(int a, int b) {
    if (b==0) return a;
    return GCD(b,a%b);
}

public static long LCM(int a, int b) {
    return a * (b / GCD(a, b));
}

public static void display(){

}
```

Comment: i try to access 'numbers' in the empty display method I created at the bottom of the code. I've tried to put ' System.out.println(GCD(numbers.getNum1(), numbers.getNum2()));' in the display method and it says it cannot resolve the symbol for 'numbers'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TwoNumbers numbers = getNumbers();
```

If you are trying to access `numbers` of main method. Then you can *not* do that, scope of `numbers` is only inside main method. You can not access it directly from other method.

Either you pass the `numbers` as parameter to `display` method or you can declare `numbers` as class level `static` variable.

```
public static void display(TwoNumbers numbers){
   //Now you have numbers inside display
}
```

Moreover, you do not need to call the `GCD` and `LCM` method again from the `display`. You can simply pass result of both methods to `display` method from `main`.

```
TwoNumbers gcdNumbers = GCD(numbers.getNum1(), numbers.getNum2());
display(gcdNumbers);
TwoNumbers lcmNumbers = LCM(numbers.getNum1(), numbers.getNum2());
display(lcmNumbers);
```